# monetdb regexp select

Tags: regex, monetdb

I'm doing some testing with MonetDB.
The gist of the query I'm trying perform (using borrowed syntax) goes like this:
`SELECT mystring FROM mytable WHERE mystring REGEXP 'myxpression';`

MonetDB does not support this syntax, but the docs claim that it supports PCRE, so this *may* be possible, still the syntax eludes me.

Comment: See https://www.monetdb.org/pipermail/users-list/2011-August/005087.html

Comment: Thank you, Viktor. It works.<br/>

To clarify for others to come:
`select name from sys.functions;`  to check if the function exists, otherwise you will need to create it.<br/>

Matching Viktor's example of function ` pcre_imatch()`, the syntax of using it (in my original question) would be <br/>

`SELECT mystring FROM mytable WHERE pcre_imatch(mystring, 'myexpression');`

Comment: Yes, thank you Wiktor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [Does MonetDB support regular expression  predicates?](https://www.monetdb.org/pipermail/users-list/2011-August/005087.html)

> The implementation is there in the MonetDB backend, the module that
>   implements it is pcre (to be found in MonetDB5 source tree).
>   I'm not sure whether it is available by default from MonetDB/SQL.
>
> If not, with these two function definition, you link SQL functions to the
>   respective implementations in MonetDB5:
>
> `-- case sensitive
>   create function pcre_match(s string, pattern string)
>     returns BOOLEAN
>     external name pcre.match;`
>
> `-- case insensitive
>   create function pcre_imatch(s string, pattern string)
>     returns BOOLEAN
>     external name pcre.imatch;`
>
> `If you need more, I'd suggest to have a look at MonetDB5/src/modules/mal/
>   pcre.mx in  the source code.`
>
> Use `select name from sys.functions;` to check if the function exists, otherwise you will need to create it.

As an example, you may use `pcre_imatch()` like this:

```
SELECT mystring FROM mytable WHERE pcre_imatch(mystring, 'myexpression');
```